# Upload array of Paths including Images

Tags: php, android, arrays, json

I'm trying to upload array of Paths Including images to my webservice, but I have issue, when I tried to upload array via post man it's work, but when I tried with android it's upload only one image.

so this code preview the images after I selected it:

```
Bundle b;

b = getIntent().getExtras();

public ArrayList<String> map = new ArrayList<String>();

if (b != null) {
        ArrayList<String> ImgData = b.getStringArrayList("IMAGE");
        for (int i = 0; i < ImgData.size(); i++) {
            map.add(ImgData.get(i).toString());
        }
    }
```

after debugging images added to `map` very well.

and here is my full `AsyncTask`:

```
 public class ImageUploadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    String sResponse = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(ImagesForAds.this, "Uploading",
                "Please wait...", true);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            String url = "my url";
            int i = Integer.parseInt(params[0]);
            Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(map.get(i));
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            entity = new MultipartEntity();

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
            byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();

            //entity.addPart("user_id", new StringBody("199"));
            //entity.addPart("club_id", new StringBody("10"));
            entity.addPart("images[]", new ByteArrayBody(data,
                    "image/jpeg", params[1]));


            Log.i(TAG, "array map: " + map.get(i));


            httpPost.setEntity(entity);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,
                    localContext);
            sResponse = EntityUtils.getContentCharSet(response.getEntity());

            System.out.println("sResponse : " + sResponse);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (dialog.isShowing())
                dialog.dismiss();
            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);

        }
        return sResponse;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String sResponse) {
        try {
            if (dialog.isShowing())
                dialog.dismiss();

            if (sResponse != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        sResponse + " Photo uploaded successfully",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                count++;
                if (count < map.size()) {
                    new ImageUploadTask().execute(count + "", "hm" + count
                            + ".jpg");
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
        }

    }
}

public Bitmap decodeFile(String filePath) {
    // Decode image size
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o);
    // The new size we want to scale to
    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 1024;
    // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
    int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
    int scale = 1;
    while (true) {
        if (width_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE)
            break;
        width_tmp /= 5;
        height_tmp /= 5;
        scale *= 5;
    }
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2);
    return bitmap;
}
```

after debugging my `data` have the same size every time, if I upload 20 images like I upload 1 image the size doesn't change.

and I call my `AsyncTask()` as below:

```
int count = 0;
new ImageUploadTask().execute(count + "", "pk" + count + ".jpg");
```

Comment: `to upload array of images `. Very confusing.  You have a string array. That array does not contain images. The strings contain the full path to image files i think.

Comment: i think you should use Picasso instead of AsyncTask if you are downloading image from url .Here is the link https://github.com/square/picasso. If the images are in local the n you can create an array of int with ids of the images then try to use it.

Comment: You have not explained what `map` would be.

Comment: @greenapps  btw this code upload one image only..
you may referring to upload via for loop ?

Comment: @Sushrita what if I want to use Async ?

Comment: `Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(map.get(i));` One image only here. And what is `i`?

Comment: @greenapps map is ArrayList

Comment: What does it contain? You are telling nothing! Why should we gues?

Comment: Updated? You are still talking about an array of images. Which is wrong.

Comment: ??? See my first comment.

Comment: `if it's contain the path only, then it won't upload any images..`. Nonsense. `map` is a string array and can contain only paths to images. Not the image files themself.

Comment: You only added irrelevant stuff and are still talking about an array of images which you have not as i already twice explained.

Comment: If you refuse to talk about an array of paths to image files and keep talking about an array of images then i see little reason helping you further.

Comment: Still waiting for you to update subject and post... Already two hours passed since my first comment. How difficult can it be?

Comment: `trying to upload array of Pathes Including images `. No. You have some image files. And you are trying to upload those image files. It happens that you have a string array list containing the paths to those files. But you are not going to upload that array list. No. You will upload some files.

Comment: Indeed. True. But you should do that of course. You should write a decent post.